# DOS protection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, denial-of-service

It seems most people advice going with some sort of hardware solution in load balancers for DOS attacks. I notice if you try to do a curl on any major/semi-major website you get a 301.

For someone with a modest budget, what's the best way to protect against DOS attacks in rails, if there is no solid solution, what's the 2nd best thing someone can do?

Comment: You may get more responses on ServerFault as well, could be worth asking in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for RoR applications you probably will use a proxy before the application servers, that server could be configured to protect from simple DoS attacks.

for example the HAProxy can be configured like that:
[antidos.cfg](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/examples/antidos.cfg)

and nginx probably has the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, CDN's aren't that expensive if you're really getting some interesting traffic. Otherwise have you looked at BFD? [Link](http://www.topwebhosts.org/tools/apf-bfd-ddos-rootkit.php)

I've used BFD on some of our old servers and it was pretty nice. Not sure how secure it actually is, we never actually got DOS'd (thankfully).